# Is there a way to duplicate and access designer drawn controls in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a set of controls in the designer and then replicate it over and over again.  Here's a picture to help visualize what I'm describing:

[image]

Currently I program the position of each control to fit properly in the panel.  Doing it this way is tedious and I have to run the program each time I make a change to make sure everything lines up the way I like it.  This is the fourth iteration of this panel and I'm getting ready to do at least two more designs for different customers who want slightly different ways of displaying the same data.

Is there a way to draw the panel and its controls in the designer, the programmatically replicate the entire set of controls, and bind different data to each of them?

Comment: Why aren't you using the designer to lay out the controls?

Comment: Because I don't know how to replicate the panel shown above.  For example, if I draw it in the designer I know the name of the RSSI label is RSSILabel1.  If I replicate or 'clone' it what is the name of that control now?  And how do I replicate the panel and all of its associated controls?  Sorry if this question is too basic but I've always done embedded programming and the GUI arena is brand new and I obviously haven't learned enough.

Comment: you can design all of these **once** on a `UserControl`, build it and you can use that `UserControl` again just by dragging-n-dropping from the toolbox.

Comment: King King, that sounds perfect.  I'll have to look into what a 'UserControl' is and just programmatically create however many of them I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow customer to move these controls around, you need:

1. Create persistence storage. Basically, your control needs to build itself from some sort of file or better - database, where all the positions and other properties will be set, saved, etc.
2. Develop a "design mode" for customer. Customer will click button "Design" and be able to move controls around, re-size them, etc. For you, in design mode you want to make controls druggable and also, you need to devise a way for resizing them too. Then customer clicks "Save" and control data should save into the persistence storage.

Now, if you ok with reimplementing multipple looks for customers and want to do it quickly - create a `UserControl`, place `TableLayoutPanel` on it and then use series of `TableLayoutPanel's` to give any look to your control. This is rather fast way. And if I only needed to do it 10 times, I would just create a control factory, and add every new implementation into it. Let customer pick out of existing implementations. Because creating designer will be rather involved effort.

Comment: At this time I just want to create the controls the way the user wants them as opposed to allowing the user to create their own version of the display.  They just want to 'use it' but they want it to be different from the way it currently is (larger spectrum analyzers, bigger text and so on.)  So your last paragraph is likely the way I'll go at this time.  Thanks!